# Is it possible to put an automatic time stamp on new files created from templates?

Tags: time, date, templates

I use Python a lot so I have created a template which has all my usual imports to save me typing them out. So far so good. I was wondering now if there is a way to put something in the template that will add the date/time to each new file I create from that template?

Basically I want to be able to right-click and open a new Python document from my template and at the top it should say:

"Created 23/02/15 14:52

import numpy as np

etc...."

I'm a total Linux/Ubuntu beginner, so this may be too complicated for me, but please try to answer with as little jargon as possible.

Comment: How to create the template - from the `~/Templates` or similar?

Comment: No, I know how to create basic templates. I have one set up with all the import statements I normally use. I want to add something that would put the time and date on it.

Comment: I meant how do you currently create them? - this determines how the solution will be reached.

Comment: I just start with a blank file and type in the things I want it to always have, then save it to the Templates folder.